# What kind of syntax is expected for a .class parameter in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I have a method that is defined like this
Method(String, String, Something.class)
Something can be x or y
I want to test Method("","",x.class) but not Method("","",y.class)(which is also thrown in the same method) so I cannot use Mockito.when(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.any()).thenReturn(/*..*/);

I need to know what to type in place of ArgumentMatchers.any() or within it so that Mockito doesn't  attempt to convert x to y neither of which are interchangeable;

Comment: How about `eq(x.class)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mockito.when(anyString(), anyString(), eq(x.class)).thenReturn(...)` does the job.

I would however advise against using too broad matchers such as `anyString` und would recommend something along the lines of `Mockito.when(eq("first"), eq("second"), eq(x.class)).thenReturn(...)` This way also the expected parameter values are tested.